# 2 decimal places output

Tags: php

My apologies if this was discussed before, but based on my study and observation from different discussions all of them doesn't work for me. I had a formula that computes a certain percentage. My problem is, it must be only in 2 decimals. It shows like `12.1212121212%` rather than `12.12%`

Here's my formula and by the way I'm using php code.

```php
$p = $c/$t * 100
```

Comment: Use `.toFixed(2);` on result. `$p = ($c/$t * 100).toFixed(2);` if you want the solution in Javascript

Comment: should it round for 2 decimals r just first 2 decimals??

Comment: @Tushar It results as a Parse Error.

Comment: @Niranjan round for 2 decimals

Comment: @Vista Read the comment again, `if you want the solution in Javascript`, and you add this in PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[`number_format()`](http://php.net/number_format)** in php

```
$p = number_format((float)( $c/$t * 100), 2, '.', '');
```

In JavaScript you can use **[`toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)**

```js
var $c = 1,
  $t = 1333,
  $p = ($c / $t * 100).toFixed(2);
document.write($p);
```

Comment: document.write($p.toFixed(2)); is it?